# Is there a better way to modulate the hash value in this case?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashcode, hashset

I noticed that a string that contains an odd number of a specific character, say 'b' has a hash value that is

```
kM+r
```

where `k` and `r` are integers and `M` is a 2's power. For example, all of the following strings result in the same value after modulating `M` if `M` is a 2's power (say 16):

```
"b"          hashCode("b") = 98,            98%16 = 2
"bbb"        hashCode("bbb") = 97314,       97314%16 = 2
"bbbbb"      hashCode("bbbbb") = 293521890, 293521890%16 = 2
...
```

If I use use the following formula ([reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VeHDbC02ENA#t=14m49s)) to modulate the hash value, all of the above strings hash to the same bucket, which is definitely *NOT* what we want.

```
int bucket_id = (hashCode(str) & 0x7fffffff) % M;
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually hash table implementations perform an additional transformation on the object hashCode before assigning a bucket. For example, here's how it's implemented in OpenJDK 8 `java.util.HashMap`:

```
static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

This makes the distribution more even. Java-7 used even more sophisticated transform, something like this:

```
int h = key.hashCode();
h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
```

Seems that it was found to be unnecessarily complicated as Java-8 simplified it.

Also the bucket is determined simply has `hash(key) & (n-1)` where `n` is number of buckets. As in the most of hash table implementations the number of buckets is the power of two, such formula works nice.

Finally to protect against collisions (accidental or intentional) even more, in Java 8 new algorithm was implemented which creates a binary tree in the buckets which contain too many elements (if the keys are `Comparable`). This makes the search in overcrowded bucket `O(log n)` instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks.